# Generator for combinations in special order

Tags: python, algorithm, generator, combinations

I've got the following recursive generator which yields each combination of numbers from `0` to `top-1`:

```
def f(width, top):
  if width == 0:
    yield []
  else:
    for v in range(top):
      for subResult in f(width - 1, top):
        yield [ v ] + subResult
```

If called as `f(3, 3)` this yields the values

```
[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2],
[0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2],
[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2],
[2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2],
[2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]
```

(Try calling it as `list(f(3,3))` to get these as a list.)

What I need to get is the same values in a *different order*:  I want the values sorted by their maximum, i. e. first the value `[0, 0, 0]`, then all values which have `1` as a maximum, i. e. `[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], ...`, then those which contain a `2`, i. e. `[0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], ...` etc.

The generator shall yield values never twice (of course) and it must be possible to call it with very large values like `f(4, 1000)` and then simply not drain it completely (so generating all values first and then sorting them after their maximum is out of the question).

The only approach I can think if is first generate all values for `f(w, 0)`, then for `f(w, 1)`, then for `f(w, 2)` and always skip the values which have been yielded before, but I have the nagging feeling that their might be a better approach:

```
def g(width, top):
  for t in range(top):
    for v in f(width, t+1):
      if t in v:
        yield v
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a preferred order for two lists with the same maximum?

Comment: Well, not really, but I think the order `g` produces is the one of the least surprise ;-)

Comment: Honestly, your implementation of `g` is pretty much how I'd do it. There are ways to avoid the skips, but the added complexity is probably not worth it.

Comment: "next permutation" version now coded (please see answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def h(width,top,top_count):
    """
    Producing lists of length 'width' containing numbers from 0 to top-1.
    Where top-1 only occur exactly top_count times.
    """
    if width == 0:
        yield []
    elif width == top_count:
        yield [top-1]*top_count
    else:
        for x in range(top-1):
            for result in h(width-1,top,top_count):
                yield [x]+result
        if top_count > 0:
            for result in h(width-1,top,top_count-1):
                yield [top-1]+result


def m(width,top):
    yield [0]*width
    for current_top in range(2,top+1):
        for top_count in range(1,width+1):
            print "=== h{}".format((width,current_top,top_count))
            for result in h(width,current_top,top_count):
                print result
                yield result

ans = [x for x in m(3,3)]
```

result:

```
=== h(3, 2, 1)
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
=== h(3, 2, 2)
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
=== h(3, 2, 3)
[1, 1, 1]
=== h(3, 3, 1)
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 1]
[2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 1]
=== h(3, 3, 2)
[0, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 1]
=== h(3, 3, 3)
[2, 2, 2]
```

Print statements are added to show each call to function `h` and its result.
The comment on `h` function should be clear enough to explain the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution myself.  I first loop over the top value, then I generate all values which have one or more of this top value.  For that I loop over the amount of top values (1 through width).  For each such amount I loop over all positions combinations these top values can have.  Then I fill these positions with the top value and the remaining values with a plain product of all values below the top value.

As code, this looks like this:

```
from itertools import product, combinations

def h(width, top):
  for t in range(top):
    for topAmount in range(1, width+1):  # how many top values are present?
      for topPositions in combinations(range(width), topAmount):
        for fillers in product(
            *[ range(t) for x in range(width-len(topPositions)) ]):
          fillers = list(fillers)
          yield [ t if i in topPositions else fillers.pop()
              for i in range(width) ]
```

But I still would like to invite you to propose more elegant solutions.  This still seems to me like a brute force method, and the way I'm building the values I yield certainly isn't the cheapest I've seen yet.

Comment: The use of `combinations` makes the code more compact, otherwise this solution has very similar idea to mine.

Comment: Right, I didn't update before posting, so I didn't see yours before mine, and now I like the compacter version I've come up with better, but the idea behind our solutions is identical :-)  (So I would always prefer your answer before mine when accepting).

Answer (score 1):

## An idea of Growing Cube

(updated from "diagonal" idea)

When I draw the task on the paper, I came to something like:

```
 |0|1|2|3|
-|-|-|-|-|
0|a|b|c|d|
-|-|-|-|-|
1|b|b|c|d|
-|-|-|-|-|
2|c|c|c|d|
-|-|-|-|-|
3|d|d|d|d|
-|-|-|-|-|
```

It shows only 2-D, in fact it has as many dimensions as is numbers.

Letters `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` show, in what groups you want to get your combinations.

What I want to say is, these groups are shaping a surface of corner of n-dimensional growing cube.

All the combinations are represented by coordinates of all the points in this cube (incl. inner space). Note, that our coordinates are using discrete values (0, 1, 2..), so there is finite number or them.

If you find a rule for scanning all coordinates on that growing cube surface, you get the generator you asked for.

Comment: Sounds promising, somehow.  Alas, there is too little flesh on that bare bone idea to help me understand your approach to a point where it gets useful :)

Comment: What I mean is: Yes, of course, that's the order of the values I want (in n-dimensional space), but can you provide an algorithm which produces them in an elegant way (more elegant than my `g`, that is)?

Comment: On second thought, no, that diagonal isn't the order I want.  You place (1,1) in group _c_, together with (0,2) and (2,0), but it should be in group _b_ together with (1,0) and (0,1).  So instead of diagonal order we rather need a squared (cubic) shape, one square containing the other.  Still, a nice thought (with that correction), and maybe this leads to a nicer solution.

Comment: Based on your graphic approach I found a solution :)  See my answer (coming soon).

Comment: @Alfe Looking forward. I run out of my capacity today, but wonder what will come. Btw you may guess, what is [my favourite book](http://www.danroam.com/the-back-of-the-napkin/)

Comment: Visualization can often help, yes, and I always prefer these approaches.  But I also found that choosing this way I sometimes am too reluctant to like the problems which do not fit it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that your function `f` yields the same values as `itertools.product`; ie. I think you can replace `f` with:

```
from itertools import product

def f(width, top):
    for p in product(range(top), repeat=width):
        yield list(p)
```

To order these values as stated in your question you can simply use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

def group_by_max_value(x, y):
    grouped = defaultdict(list)
    for k, g in groupby(f(x, y), key=max):
        grouped[k].extend(list(g))
    return [grouped[k] for k in sorted(grouped.keys())]
```

Revised function definition which yields sorted values without having to generate the whole sequence first.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

def lazy_group_by_max_value(width, top):
    grouped = defaultdict(list)
    # using `itertools.product` with a `range` object
    # guarantees that the product-tuples are emitted
    # in sorted order.
    ps = product(range(top), repeat=width)
    for k, g in groupby(ps, key=max):
        xs = list(g)
        grouped[k].extend(xs)
        # if xs[-1] is of the form (0, 0, .., 0), (1, 1, .., 1), .., (n, n, .., n) etc
        # then we have found all the maxes for `k`, because all future
        # sequences will contain at least one value which is greater than k.
        if set(xs[-1]) == {k}:
            # `pop` (ie. remove) the values from `grouped`
            # which are associated with key `k`.
            all_maxes_for_k = grouped.pop(k)
            for coll in all_maxes_for_k:
                yield coll
```

Comment: Doesn't `groupby()` only work for values coming in chunks already grouped?

Comment: @superjump OP does not want to sort, your `sorted` and `max` are sorting.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky OP says: "I want the values sorted by their maximum". Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @superjump Yes, sorted by maximum is a requirement, but there is also "generating all values first and then sorting them after their maximum is out of the question" requirement.

Comment: I also stated that I cannot collect all values first to apply a proper sorting afterwards.  I just stated that "sorted order" to make clear in which order I want to yield them.

Comment: @Alfe Does the revised function do what you want?

Comment: For small input, yes.  For larger input it is much too costly.  Try it with `for i in lazy_group_by_max_value(12, 10000): print i` and you will see only one value, and then your routine will gobble up all memory available to perform the task and never print a second line.

Comment: You have to understand that the advantage of a generator sometimes lies in the option to not drain it (I just take the first 1000 generated values and ignore the rest).  Your answer is based on the idea that the generator surely will be drained (all values will be generated until a `StopIteration` occurs), and in that case your solution is working quite well, AFAICS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm to generate the next lexicographic permutation (by the way, I also like the idea of each set as numbers with a different radix; e.g., base 1 base 2, etc.):

While not all digits are maximized

        Augment all digits to the right of the left-most maximum according
  to the following algorithm:

            Augment the right-most digit that is not maximized and set all digits 
        to the right of it to zero

        If they are maximized, augment the first digit to the left. If it is maximized, set all digits to the

        right of it to zero; otherwise, set the right-most digit to maximum and the digits in between to zero.

Python code:

```
def nextP(perm,top):
  if all (i == top for i in perm):
    return None

  left_max = perm.index(top)

  if all (i == top for i in perm[left_max:]):
    perm[left_max - 1] = perm[left_max - 1] + 1
    perm[left_max:] = [0] * (len(perm) - left_max - 1) + ([0] if perm[left_max - 1] == top else [top])
  else:
    right_max = len(perm) - next(x[0] for x in enumerate(perm[left_max + 1:][::-1]) if x[1] < top) - 1
    perm = perm[:right_max] + [perm[right_max] + 1] + [0] * (len(perm) - right_max - 1)

  return perm
```

Example:

```
permutation = [0,0,2]

while permutation:
  print permutation
  permutation = nextP(permutation,2)

[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 2]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

First notice that you can easily generate the list of unique solutions containing `2` as the maximum using the list of unique solutions containing `1` as the maximum. Just increment all possible combinations of `1`. For example, from `[1,0,1]` you simply generate `[2,0,1]`, `[1,0,2]`, and `[2,0,2]`. This suggests the following solution:

```
import itertools

def g(n) :
    if n == 0 :
        yield [ 0,0,0 ]
    else :
        for x in g(n-1) : # for each solution containing `1` as the maximum
            idx = [ i for (i,xi) in enumerate(x) if xi == n-1 ] # locate the '1' to be incremented
            for j in xrange(1,len(idx)+1) : # increment one '1', then two '1', then three '1', etc
                for tup in itertools.combinations( idx, j ) : # all possible combinations of j '1'
                    y = list(x)
                    for t in tup : # prepare the new solution
                        y[t] += 1
                    yield y
```

Examples:

```
list( g(0) )

[[0, 0, 0]]

list( g(1) )

[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

list( g(2) )

[[2, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 2],
 [2, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 0],
 [2, 2, 0],
 [2, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 2],
 [2, 0, 2],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [1, 1, 2],
 [2, 2, 1],
 [2, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: I really like that approach!  I like the recursiveness, especially.  It also mixes combinations with products (even if not explicitly), so it is another hint that this approach probably is the most effective solution to this problem! :-)